# How do I optimize virtualbox to perform as well as Parallels?

Tags: virtualbox

My college classes require a windows setup (I'm on a Mac). I considered dual booting, but decided against it and chose to virtualise. Initially, I wanted to go with Parallels Desktop but it's a bit on the expensive side. So, I'm running Windows 10 on virtualbox and not so surprisingly, its a bit sluggish. How does Parallels virtualise Windows so efficiently? Is there any way to modify my Virtualbox setup to mimic that?

Comment: I wouldn't even attempt to try tweak VB to be as fast as Parallels, it's just not capable. Have a look at VMWare Fusion instead, there's a 'free for home use' version.

Comment: "How does Parallels virtualize Windows so efficiently?" - To put it simply it's a more mature product that has had millions of dollars invested into it.  VirtualBox on the other than is a open source project managed by Oracle. BootCamp will ultimately be the best solution if you are worried about performance.

Comment: Make sure you have given it 4 GB of memory and 2 cores.  Also consider Fusion for this task. You can get a trial.

Comment: @Tetsujin so VMWare is faster than VBox?

Comment: @Ramhound I did consider using BootCamp. But with a 120GB internal SSD, that won't leave much space for either OS.

Comment: @John I gave it 2 cores and 4.5 GB RAM

Comment: Everything is faster than VBox. Parallels, imo, is fastest, but most expensive - I guess you get what you pay for… For max performance allocate your entire physical core count, which lets HT sort out the rest. It wants 8GB minimum, but as much as you can give it whilst still leaving 8 for the Mac.

Comment: A 120 GB SSD drive is too small for 2 operating systems .  VBOX and the Mac may be swapping in and out of disk to make things work.

Comment: @Tetsujin and John, I got VMWare with the free personal use license and its way faster and smoother than VBox. Thanks for the tip!